# Automatically Share Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a script to automatically share files. However, I can only share one file. I want to share multiple files with different people. I would be glad if you help.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Automated Sharing")
  .addItem("Share file now", "shareFile")
  .addToUi();
}



function shareFile() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const fileID = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
  const emailAndPermissions = sheet.getRange(2,2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  const fileToShare = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);

  emailAndPermissions.forEach(function(emailAndPermissions) {
    if(emailAndPermissions[1] === "Viewer") {
      fileToShare.addViewer(emailAndPermissions[0]);
    }
    else if (emailAndPermissions[1] === "Commenter") {
      fileToShare.addCommenter(emailAndPermissions[0]);
    }
    else if (emailAndPermissions[1] === "Editor") {
      fileToShare.addEditor(emailAndPermissions[0]);
    }
    else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Permission must be 'Viwer', 'Commenter' or 'Editor'. Please check input.")
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About `I want to share multiple files with different people.`, in your situation, where do you want to retrieve the file IDs corresponding to each email address? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.